# Why is numpy returning tuples to me?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can someone help me to wrap my head around numpy?

In the following code I expect that `col1` would give me an array of shape `(2, 3)` just as the `expected_arr`. But apparently `col1` seems to have shape `(2,)`. I suppose that means it's an array with two tupels (instead of an array with two arrays with 3 values each.

```
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import deque 

vals = np.array([
  [[1, 2, 3], False],
  [[4, 5, 6], False]
])

col1 = vals[:,0]

print(col1)
print(col1.shape)

expected_arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

print(expected_arr)
print(expected_arr.shape)
```

So, what I want is, given a structure of `vals`, I'd like to get the first column so that the output is an array of shape `(2,3)`.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create this array:

```
vals = np.array([
  [[1, 2, 3], False],
  [[4, 5, 6], False]
])
```

this is not a recatngular array, so numpy makes it an object array

```
vals.dtype
dtype('O')
```

with shape `(2,2)`.  The objects in the array are two lists and two boolean values.

When you index just the list, the resulting array still has `dtype('O')`:

```
vals[:,0].dtype
dtype('O')
```

which means it's still an array of list objects.  To convert this to a full array, you'll need to use `np.vstack`

```
np.vstack(vals[:,0])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Object arrays aren't really effcient in `numpy`.  They don't take advantage of any of the optimizations and casue lots of problems converting back and forth.  You can try [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html), or seperate arrays.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

In this case the array `vals` was constructed from a structure that cannot be interpreted as an array (i.e. contiguous block of same-sized elements) of one of the basic numerical types. Your list from which the array is being created is a list of mixed-type elements.

When this happens `numpy`'s array constructor tries to create a generic array with the `dtype` being "`object`", i.e. just plain Python object (actually, references to them). It is quite analogous to a pointer array in C.  `vals` is thus a 2 x 2 array holding in it the objects

```
the list `[1, 2, 3]` | the bool `False`
---------------------------------------
the list `[4, 5, 6]` | the bool `False`
```

as a row-major array in memory.

As `col1` is a slice-notation indexing of the 2-dimensional array `vals`, you get an array of one-dimension that contains two elements, namely the two Python lists.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!